# document.onkeyup only when not typing in textbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to make a navigation system using document.onkeyup where pressing left arrow on the keyboard forwards the user to the previous ID and the same with the right arrow forwarding to the next ID.

I'd also like to use the R key to bring people to a random ID, however there is also a search and login form so when the user presses R, while typing, they will be forwarded to another page.

How can I avoid this?

here's my code

```
$AddToSite_JavaScript = '<script>
document.onkeyup=checkKeycode;
function checkKeycode(e)
{
    var keycode;
    if(window.event) keycode=window.event.keyCode;
    else if(e) keycode=e.which;

    if(keycode=="37") window.location.href=\''. $WebsiteRoot ."/". $PreviousId ."-". $PreviousTitle .'\';
    else if(keycode=="39") window.location.href=\''. $WebsiteRoot ."/". $NextId ."-". $NextTitle .'\';
    else if(keycode=="13" || keycode=="82") window.location.href=\''. $WebsiteRoot ."/random" .'\';
}
</script>';
```

Comment: What you mean by ID ? Do you mean some HTML element ?

Comment: We'd need to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: by ID I mean the php page id (page.php?id=2)

Comment: 13 is "Enter"; 82 is "R"

Comment: Yes, I know, I was still working on it :P i wanna do both enter and R like I just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only using inputs for text: throwing the following code after `keycode=="82"` will do the trick:

`&& e.srcElement.tagName != "INPUT"`

Essentially, it just checks if the key stroke originated from an input box.

If you don't want pressing enter in an input to trigger it: put your existing code in () and then add this.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, figured it would be something simple

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code:

```
> var keycode;
> if(window.event) keycode=window.event.keyCode;
> else if(e) keycode=e.which;
```

would be better as:

```
var keycode, target;
e = e || window.event;
if (e) {
  keycode = e.keyCode || e.which
  target = e.target || e.srcElement;
}
```

Note that `event.srcElement` is IE specific, W3C compliant browsers support `event.target`.

Now `target` is the element whose handler called the function, so later you can do:

```
... && target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input' ...
```